Is there a sf command to list all apex classes in my Org?
I want to use an sf command to list all the names of the apex classes I have in my Org.Is there a command I can use ?

sf org list metadata provides a JSON-formatted output of any kind of metadata in the Metadata API, including Apex Classes. In addition, sf data query can return the records in CSV format.
sf org list metadata -o org-alias -m ApexClass -f output.json

sf data query -o org-alias -q "select name from ApexClass"

